# The bottom view is getting blocked by the top view

Tags: android, view, android-view

I have a really annoying problem with fitting two custom views to work together. I'm trying to display these two views in an android activity, but one of them takes the whole viewable space of the activity and the other is placed under it. The first view only uses a small part of the space and the rest is trasparent, but it only works when its width and height is at `match_parent` so the other view is displayed under it, but it is being blocked from receiving any touch events. here is how they looks like:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

the xml code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background_app" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.fortysevendeg.android.swipelistview.SwipeListView
        xmlns:swipe="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/example_lv_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:listSelector="#00000000"
        swipe:swipeActionLeft="dismiss"
        swipe:swipeBackView="@+id/back"
        swipe:swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList="true"
        swipe:swipeFrontView="@+id/front"
        swipe:swipeMode="both" 
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
</LinearLayout>

<com.touchmenotapps.widget.radialmenu.semicircularmenu.SemiCircularRadialMenu
        android:id="@+id/radial_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:padding="1dip" />
</FrameLayout>
```

What I'm trying to do is to be able to touch the bottom where the top view is transparent, and be able to touch the top view where it's not transparent. I tried arranging the xml in a different way but it keeps crashing, this is the only way it worked, but this problem appeared.

Links to the custom Views:

- Radial-Menu-Widget: github.com/strider2023/Radial-Menu-Widget-Android
- SwipeListView library: github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview
- SwipeListView sample: github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview-sample

What I'm trying to accomplish here is something similar to [Catch Notes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.threebanana.notes&hl=en) app. If there are other ways, or other libraries you can suggest, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok try this: copy the source code of `SemiCircularRadialMenu.class` in your project and modify

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
```

Because this method always returns true and captures all touch events, so also the touch event for `SwipeListView` listener. I solved it in this way.

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but others may find this answer helpful. Without modifying the source of your custom views, I don't think you can get the behavior you want. But getting the two custom views to work onto the same screen might be as simple as changing your root layout to a LinearLayout, adding weight to the inner layout, and setting the height of the second custom view to wrap_content. By having only one widget with a weight, it will get all the space left after the others are laid out. Here's your layout with the changes applied:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_app"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="100" >

        <com.fortysevendeg.android.swipelistview.SwipeListView
            xmlns:swipe="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/example_lv_list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:listSelector="#00000000"
            swipe:swipeActionLeft="dismiss"
            swipe:swipeBackView="@+id/back"
            swipe:swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList="true"
            swipe:swipeFrontView="@+id/front"
            swipe:swipeMode="both" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.touchmenotapps.widget.radialmenu.semicircularmenu.SemiCircularRadialMenu
        android:id="@+id/radial_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:padding="1dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If you need to height of the second view to be more expandable, you can wrap it in another LinearLayout with a weight and adjust the two weights to apportion the screen height between them. The individual weight values aren't special; it's their value relative to the sum of all the weights that determines how much height each one gets. I like to make my total values add up to 100 so I can think of the weights as percentages.